# "Creation of DB2Driver object failed: CCSID value is not valid" when launching Grails app on jetty on an IBM

Tags: grails, db2, jetty, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to get a Grails web-app going on jetty-7.6.3 on an IBM AS400.  When I do, I get an error that boils down to:

```
Caused by: 
java.sql.SQLException: INTERNAL ERROR:  Creation of DB2Driver object for registering with DriverManager failed. -> com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2JDBCDataException: CCSID value is not valid.
at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2ErrorDriver.throwSavedExceptions(DB2ErrorDriver.java:113)
at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2ErrorDriver.handleURLProcessing(DB2ErrorDriver.java:296)
at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2ErrorDriver.acceptsURL(DB2ErrorDriver.java:149)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:386)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:224)
at $Proxy16.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.SpringLobHandlerDetectorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLobHandlerDetectorFactoryBean.java:72)
...
```

I can provide more of the stacktrace if that would be helpful.

Here is my datasource:

```
dataSource{
  dbCreate = "update"
  pooled = true
  url = "jdbc:db2:*local;naming=system;libraries=LIBV;errors=full"
  driverClassName = "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver"
  username = "user"
  password = "pass"
  dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect.class
}
```

I have no idea where to start on this or which file has the wrong CCSID.  I've looked through all the files for my web-app and they seem to be fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Execute a `CHGJOB CCSID(37)` on the IBM i job, this will change the CCSID to 37 from the default 65535.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Grails programmer but I'm familiar with IBM i.  IBM Support document [29290926](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/9ea41ee0c6099d1e86256caa006e4b59) says that CCSID 65535 is not allowed.

Quite a few midrange machines were sold and set up decades ago, when there was no CCSID.  As the operating system evolved, the notion of CCSID - Coded Character Set ID - was introduced.  When that happened, people upgrading to the new version of the OS were assigned a default CCSID: 65535.  CCSID 65535 in effect says 'I have no idea how your files are encoded'.  In effect, all the files are treated as though they are binary data like a JPG or an EXE file.

The recommendation back then was to not allow the default, but to assign a CCSID that described the actual encoding.  Where I am in the US, that CCSID is 37 - US English.  There is a system value called QCCSID which will set this system-wide.  Another approach is to change the user profile involved.  `CHGUSRPRF username CCSID(37)`

Comment: We use this user often in our programs to make a connection to the database.  Would I be correct in assuming that the only ill-effect of changing to CCSID 37 would be if there were characters in our database that are not recognized as US English?

Comment: Pretty much.  Unless you run a multi-language shop, all your users are already typing US English characters with their US  English keyboards.

Comment: Ended up changing the system value (QCCSID) which the user was set to use (I assume by default) as our main IBM guy said that there wasn't any reason to keep CCSID 65535 and we have been changing some of the systems that had that value to 37 anyway.  WRKSYSVAL QCCSID